# Apply script to each folder in a drive

Tags: python, loops, directory, duplicates, data-cleaning

I am working on a data cleanup in a network drive. The drive has 1000+ folders, and those folders have several subfolders. The script that I got from G4G (seen below) prompts me to select a folder. I can click on one of my 1000+ folders, and the data is cleaned up properly (duplicates are deleted). However, I'd like to loop the command through the whole drive to avoid clicking on folders for hours. I cannot select the drive as my folder because duplicate file names between the first folders in the drive should not be considered duplicates.

EDIT:
I'll give an example to clarify.

Z:/Folder1 and Z:/Folder2 both have several files named "text.txt," immediately inside of the folders and within the subdirectories of the folders. Folder1 and Folder2, amongst all "text.txt" files immediately inside and within its subdirectories, should each be left with one "text.txt." If the current script is applied to Folder1 and Folder2 individually, then the desired result of one "text.txt" file existing in Folder1 and one existing in Folder2 is accomplished. If the script is applied to the Z drive, then between Folder1 and Folder2, there would only be one "text.txt," and one of the folders would be without a file named "text.txt."

How can I apply this script to each first folder in the drive without having to manually click on each folder?

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

# Importing required libraries.
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import hashlib
from pathlib import Path

# We don't want the GUI window of
# tkinter to be appearing on our screen
Tk().withdraw()

# Dialog box for selecting a folder.
file_path = askdirectory(title="Select a folder")

# Listing out all the files
# inside our root folder.
list_of_files = os.walk(file_path)

# In order to detect the duplicate
# files we are going to define an empty dictionary.
unique_files = dict()

for root, folders, files in list_of_files:

    # Running a for loop on all the files
    for file in files:

        # Finding complete file path
        file_path = Path(os.path.join(root, file))

        # Converting all the content of
        # our file into md5 hash.
        Hash_file = hashlib.md5(open(file_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()

        # If file hash has already #
        # been added we'll simply delete that file
        if Hash_file not in unique_files:
            unique_files[Hash_file] = file_path
        else:
            if file.endswith((".txt",".bmp")):
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(f"{file_path} has been deleted")
```

Comment: What is the question? This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can run it for drive as main folder and you have to only skip this first folder using `if/else` - something like `if root != "your drive" : ... run code ...`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and answer. I originally kept my question short to avoid a TLDR response, but I acknowledge that I should explain my question more clearly. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run it for your `drive` and use `if/else` to skip first folder

```
list_of_files = os.walk("your drive")

for root, folders, files in list_of_files:

    if root != "your drive":

        for file in files:

            # ... code ...
```

This way you can skip also other (sub)folders.

---

OR you can use `next()` to skip some element from `os.walk()`  because `os.walk()` doesn't give directly list with all elements but `generator`.

```
list_of_files = os.walk("your drive")

next(list_of_files)   # skip first item

for root, folders, files in list_of_files:

    for file in files:

        # ... code ...
```